# What algorithm does YouTube use to change playback speed without affecting audio pitch?

Tags: youtube, signal-processing, audio-player, pitch-shifting

Youtube has an option to change the playback speed of videos that speeds up or slows down a video's audio without affecting its pitch. I know that there are a number of different algorithms that can do this, but I am curious as to **which specific algorithm Youtube uses** because it seems to work rather well.

Also, are there any open source libraries implementing this algorithm?

Comment: A few years ago they were using a version of the PICOLA algorithm in some apps.  The iOS app might have also used the built-in iOS TimePitch Audio Unit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this article on the subject dating back to 2017, I presume it's still valid or should give you some pointers: https://www.googblogs.com/variable-speed-playback-on-mobile/

It reads, in part:

> "On Android, we used the Sonic library for our audio manipulation in ExoPlayer. Sonic uses PICOLA, a time domain based algorithm. On iOS, AVplayer has a built in playback rate feature with configurable time stretching."